# Exception encountered during context initialization - While configuring a HibernateTemplate Bean using Java Configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-orm

Not able to configure the hibernate getting context initialization exception, Have tried the alternate versions of Hibernate dependency, and although the table is created in DB, I think there is some issue related to Bean.

Student Entity

```
package com.spring.orm.Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private long studentId;
    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name = "student_city")
    private String studentCity;
    
    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public String getStudentCity() {
        return studentCity;
    }
    public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }
    public Student() {
    }
    public Student(long studentId, String studentName, String studentCity) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

}
```

Student Dao

```
package com.spring.orm.Dao;

import com.spring.orm.Entity.Student;

public interface StudentDao {

    public Student insert(Student student);

}
```

Student Dao Impl

```
package com.spring.orm.Dao.Impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;

import com.spring.orm.Dao.StudentDao;
import com.spring.orm.Entity.Student;

public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public Student insert(Student student) {
        Student st = (Student) hibernateTemplate.save(student);
        return st;
    }

}
```

Hibernate Configurations

```
package com.spring.orm.Config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.spring.orm.Dao.Impl.StudentDaoImpl;
import com.spring.orm.Entity.Student;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        System.out.println("Configured Hibernate properties");
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("qwsx##HG##123");
        System.out.println("Configured datasource");
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.spring.orm.Entity");
        System.out.println("Configured session factory");
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "hibernateTemplate")
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(){
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplateObj = new HibernateTemplate();
        hibernateTemplateObj.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return hibernateTemplateObj;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "studentImpl")
    public StudentDaoImpl getStudentDao(){
        StudentDaoImpl studentDaoImpl = new StudentDaoImpl();
        return studentDaoImpl;
    }

}
```

App.java

```
package com.spring.orm;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig;
import com.spring.orm.Dao.StudentDao;
import com.spring.orm.Entity.Student;

/\*\*

* Hello world!
* 

\*/
public class App
{
public static void main( String\[\] args )
{
System.out.println( "Application started!" );

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HibernateConfig.class);
        StudentDao stDaoObj = context.getBean("studentImpl", StudentDao.class);
    
        Student st = new Student();
    
        st.setStudentId(44);
        st.setStudentName("Harshit Gupta");
        st.setStudentCity("Karera");
    
        stDaoObj.insert(st);
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>com.spring.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>springorm</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
      <name>springorm</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
          <version>9.0.80</version>
      </dependency>
    
    
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
          <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Exception

```
    Application started! Configured Hibernate properties Configured datasource Configured session factory Mar 10, 2024 9:04:26 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final Mar 10, 2024 9:04:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect Mar 10, 2024 9:04:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect WARN: HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead Mar 10, 2024 9:04:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] Mar 10, 2024 9:04:27 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: Factory method 'getHibernateTemplate' threw exception with message: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: Factory method 'getHibernateTemplate' threw exception with message: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)        
         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959)        
         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)        
         at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)        
         at com.spring.orm.App.main(App.java:20) 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate]: 
    Factory method 'getHibernateTemplate' threw exception with message: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647)         
    ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion        
         at com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig.getHibernateTemplate(HibernateConfig.java:57)        
         at com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$getHibernateTemplate$3(<generated>)        
         at com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>)        
         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)        
         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)        
         at com.spring.orm.Config.HibernateConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getHibernateTemplate(<generated>)        
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)        
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)        
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)      
    ... 15 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion        
         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)        
         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)        
         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)         ... 24 more
```

Not able to configure hibernate template

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion` looks like a required jar is missing from the classpath. What dependency management tool are you using? Maven/Gradle? Please share pom or build.gradle files to understand the issue.

Comment: I'm using Maven sharing a pom as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I was looking for an answer on different forums but on simple googling, I got to know that in the spring 5+ version, HibernateTemplate is deprecated instead we should inject the `sessionFactory` object directly in the 'Student Dao Impl' and it worked for me.

Updated hibernate Configurations

```
package com.spring.orm.Config;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.spring.orm.Dao.Impl.StudentDaoImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    public Properties getHibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        System.out.println("Configured Hibernate properties");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("qwsx##HG##123");
        System.out.println("Configured datasource");
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.spring.orm.Entity");
        System.out.println("Configured session factory");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "studentImpl")
    public StudentDaoImpl getStudentDao(){
        StudentDaoImpl studentDaoImpl = new StudentDaoImpl();
        return studentDaoImpl;
    }
}
```

updated Student Dao Impl

```
package com.spring.orm.Dao.Impl;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.orm.Dao.StudentDao;
import com.spring.orm.Entity.Student;


@Repository
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void insert(Student student) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(student);
    }


    @Override
    public void deleteStudentById(int id) {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setStudentId(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().remove(st);
    }


    // public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    //     this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    // }
    
}
```

Rest all the files are same

You can get more details here:-

[Class HibernateTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.13.RELEASE_to_4.3.14.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.14.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate dropped Criteria-api before jakarta.annotations-api was introduced. Welcome to dependency hell!

Thats why the `hibernate5` in

> import org.springframework.orm.**hibernate5**.HibernateTemplate;

But your pom have hibernate version 6x.

Use this dependencies instead:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.80</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

By the way: `spring-data-jpa` transitievly bind compatible `spring-core`, `spring-orm` and `spring-context` aswell.

Comment: I don't know whether this will work or not because on simple googling I got to know In spring 5+ versions, HibernateTemplate was deprecated due to some performance issue instead we can directly inject the sessionFactory object in dao impl and can use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to perform CRUD operations.